# Modified BFS tree traversal

Tags: algorithm, tree, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

I was trying to implement a tree traversal algorithm similar to BFS, but with a small modification. Whenever we are jumping to the next line, we should start from the nearest child (child of last node in the row) instead of the farthest node of next row. How can I modify the BFS code to achieve this?

This is the original BFS code:

```
   public void bfs()
   {
      // BFS uses Queue data structure

      Queue q = new LinkedList();

      q.add(rootNode);
      visited[rootNode] = true;

      printNode(rootNode);

      while( !q.isEmpty() )
      {
         int n, child;

         n = (q.peek()).intValue();

         child = getUnvisitedChildNode(n);    // Returns -1 if no unvisited niode left     

         if ( child != -1 )
         {  // Found an unvisted node 

            visited[child] = true;        // Mark as visited

            printNode(child);

            q.add(child);      // Add to queue 
         }
         else
         {
            q.remove();                  // Process next node
         }
      }
   }
```

This is how my desired modified BFS should work:

[image]

[image]

Comment: A stack instead of a queue should do.

Comment: That looks like a zigzag pattern. Is that what you want?

Comment: Can you post how the output will look like once your implementation is successful ? I think based on what I understand it should be something like 0, 3,4,5,2,6,7,1,8,9

Comment: *"we should start from the right-most child"*: this is not happening in the image. "1" is at the left.

Comment: You would need to modify the implementation of `getUnvisitedChildNode` for that as well, so better add its code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have 2 stacks - one for the current level, one for the next level.

Do peek / pop from the current level and push to the next level. If the current level is empty, swap the two stacks (so the next level becomes the current level and vice versa).

It would look something like this:
(like your code but with `q` replaced by `current` and `next`, and swapping the two)

```java
Stack current, next;
// ...
current.push(rootNode);
while (!current.isEmpty() || !next.isEmpty())
{
   if (current.isEmpty())
   {
      current = next;
      next.clear();
   }
   int n = current.peek();
   // ...
   next.add(child);
   // ...
   current.pop();
}
```

`getUnvisitedChildNode` would also need to change (since it currently presumably forces a left-to-right direction on an individual node). One option would be to pass a direction down to decide whether to return the next child from the left or right side (which you invert when swapping `next` and `current`).

---

It is possible to do this without changing `getUnvisitedChildNode`, but would require some "ugly" code - the basic idea would be to call `getUnvisitedChildNode`in a loop until you have all children of some given node, throwing all of those children into an array (without processing i.e. printing them), then choosing the direction in which to process them using a similar direction variable as described above.

If you already have access to the children array, you can probably just loop over that directly from either the left or right.